# Why I have this error in Tensorflow trainig model

Tags: python, debugging

I have a Tensorflow NN to classify cat and dogs images. It is in Python, Anaconda and Jupyter, and database is 25K pictures.
It runs correctly until compilation.
But when I start training a have an error. Could you please give comments how to fix it?

This is the error

```
TRAINING
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

tensorboardDenso = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/denso')
modeloDenso.fit(X, y, batch_size=32,
                validation_split=0.15,
                epochs=100,
                callbacks=[tensorboardDenso])

Epoch 1/100

ERROR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11448\107696963.py in <module>
      2 
      3 tensorboardDenso = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/denso')
----> 4 modeloDenso.fit(X, y, batch_size=32,
      5                 validation_split=0.15,
      6                 epochs=100,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in _write_keras_model_train_graph(self)
   2270         # If the train_function is a `tf.function`, we can write out a graph
   2271         if hasattr(train_fn, 'function_spec'):
-> 2272           summary_ops_v2.graph(train_fn._concrete_stateful_fn.graph)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2273 
   2274   def _write_keras_model_summary(self):

AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute '_concrete_stateful_fn'
```

Comment: Please share the required code for reproducing the error. Also check if this helps: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15699

Comment: Here is source code of original project:  https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbEpvUUhZREJxRmtNeF9jUFIwZ1daUDFaTTQ1QXxBQ3Jtc0tta2J5OWJHa2NfZXFzNTl6UjI4OHJWUXRBNVF1T19ySFZKcjZoX05HZ01Fb2Fnc180U0tLQlBla0FhYklOYW5sWi1SS193bzM0dFVrWXI5WC0ycVNfMEl3SW9nUTROR0F3X0hFRjNFQUJoZmNTbGFtVQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fcolab.research.google.com%2Fdrive%2F1DQc8a-WOTctenvoy5T0lWUXn47EuteCy%3Fusp%3Dsharing&v=DbwKbsCWPSg

Comment: Already found how to fix. I just replaced '= TensorBoard' for tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard in the training code. Hope it helps to any who need it

Comment: Consider adding the Python tag to your question.

Comment: Of course. Done

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in Kamero's comment, the solution is to change the import from:

`from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard`

to:

`from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard`